# Real time map updating

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a web service that takes user location periodically.

I want to create a desktop application that takes those values and shows the real time position of user on a map automatically.

What is the best method I can follow to get real time updates?
Can I use `Ajax`? Does it support auto refresh?

Is there a better method which supports auto refresh and also display real time data?

Thank you..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the SignalR library. There is a server-part and a clients part (Javascript, rich client) etc.).
You could trigger the update in the client if the WebService was called. So the client is notified and could update his data accordingly.
How many clients are connected? Maybe some other message bus like library would be more appropriate?

Comment: I want to display those updates in a single desktop application. There may be number of mobile applications which are sending there locations to the web service.

Comment: That would probably work nicely with SignalR.
Just trigger on the WebService if a new dataset is available and put some data into the event. The client will receive the data asynchronously. So you do not need to implement some polling etc.